# Write Excel sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
package com.testCases;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class PoiWriteExcelFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                    "D:\\User\\ExecutionResults.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1"); 
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                Cell cell=null;
                cell=worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("Keyword" +i);
                cell=worksheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue("PASS" +i);
                workbook.write(fileOut);
            }
        } 

}
```

Throws exception. what goes wrong here...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.testCases.PoiWriteExcelFile.main(PoiWriteExcelFile.java:30)

Comment: Could you include a question that describes what you're trying to do, and a description of what's going wrong, instead of just a code extract?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have given.. can you check now..??

Comment: You're getting a NullPointerException because you're dereferencing a `null` value. Break those `getRow()` and `getCell()` calls out to separate lines to make it easier to debug, and refer to the [POI documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html) to see when those calls might return null and what to do about it.

Comment: Changed this as you said:    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

    XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);
    row.getCell(0).setCellValue("Keyword" +i);
    workbook.write(fileOut);
   }
  }  Still same error

Comment: Are you creating a new file or its an existing file on your system?

Comment: I am using existing file name..

Comment: AFAIK Newly created workbook will have no sheets cells or rows - you need to create them yourself. Trying to just `get` them will return null

Comment: Since you get an NPE, maybe you should start checking for `null`s on every intermediate result. Then tell us, what statement (or substatement) exactly throws the NPE - maybe the problem resolves itself then.

Comment: `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("D:\\User\\ExecutionResults.xlsx"));`

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me. Can you give it a try?

```
`import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filePath = "D:\\xecutionResults.xlsx";
        Workbook workbook;
        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);

            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

                if(row == null)
                    row = sheet.createRow(i);

                Cell cell=row.getCell(0);

                if(cell == null)
                    cell = row.createCell(0, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

                cell.setCellValue("Keyword" +i);

                cell=row.getCell(1);

                if(cell == null)
                    cell = row.createCell(1, Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue("PASS" +i);

                System.out.println("1");
            }
            fis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //close out/in streams
        }

    } 

}`
```

[image: resulted file]

Comment: use `XSSFWorkbook(java.io.File file)` or `XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream is)` to load your excel sheet

Comment: it is not adding anything.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

Comment: Make sure your document is not corrupted. Mine is working fine, given you screenshot also.

Answer (score 0):

here the code :

```
public void WriteStudentData() {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
    int excel_length=10;
    for(i=0;i<excel_length;i++){
    Row row1 = sheet.createRow(i);
    //setting cells values
    for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(m);
    if (m == 0) {
    cell.setCellValue("Keyword"+i);
                  }
    if (m == 1) {
       cell.setCellValue("PASS"+i);
         }
  }
  }
 //creating excel file
  FileOutputStream fileOut;
  try {
   fileOut = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Student.xlsx");
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }


   }
```

Comment: which details? you need to know

Comment: this code for creating a nex excel file but if you want to use an exsiting file you should check the cell value before